# I cannot convert my pandas dataframe to a tensorflow dataset - Get a Value Error

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets, data-conversion

My data source - https://www.kaggle.com/vbookshelf/respiratory-sound-database
Tensroflow version - 2.4.0

After a bit of Data Cleaning my pandas Dataframe looked like this:
[image]

My objective is to make Deep Learning Model for a Classification task, so I read the audio files with scipy.io wavefile and put the array as a feature in the data frame.
[image]

All the values of the audio have a shape of (882000,)

My problem is that I want to convert my Pandas Dataframe into a Tensorflow Dataset.
I get this error: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type NumPy.ndarray).

I tried using tf.convert_to_tensor and still get the same error. What should I do?

Comment: Did you tried to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` as suggested in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe)?

Comment: Yes I tried that that too didn't work

Comment: Can you share sample data and code that you have tried so far? to replicate your issue. so that we can try to help you. Thanks!